# How do i implement this python tkinter tooltip without overriding the button press animation

Tags: python, tkinter, tooltip

I'm using the following script for assigning and managing tooltips. It works, but with a small disadvantage. The button widgets I assign tooltips to no longer have a click down animation unless the tooltip script executes after 500ms. Any ideas? If possible, i want to keep the native button behavior at any time AND have a 500ms wait before showing a tooltip.

```
class ToolTip(object):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        self.widget = widget
        self.tipwindow = None
        self.id = None
        self.x = self.y = 0
    def showtip(self, text):
        self.text = text
        if self.tipwindow or not self.text: return
        x,y,cx,cy = self.widget.bbox("insert")
        x = x + self.widget.winfo_rootx() +15
        y = y + cy + self.widget.winfo_rooty() +65
        self.tipwindow = tw = Toplevel(self.widget)
        tw.wm_overrideredirect(1)
        tw.wm_geometry("+%d+%d"%(x,y))
        label = Label(tw, text=self.text, justify=LEFT,background="#ffffe0", relief=SOLID, borderwidth=1,font=("tahoma", "8", "normal"))
        label.pack(ipadx=1)
    def hidetip(self):
        tw = self.tipwindow
        self.tipwindow = None
        if tw: tw.destroy()

def createToolTip(self,widget,text):
    toolTip = self.ToolTip(widget)
    def enter(event): root.after(500,show(event))
    def show(event): toolTip.showtip(text)
    def leave(event): toolTip.hidetip()
    widget.bind('<Enter>', enter)
    widget.bind('<Leave>', leave)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug in your code. You have this:

```
def enter(event): root.after(500,show(event))
```

However, the argument to `after` should be a reference to a function, not an actual function call. Change it to this:

```
def enter(event): root.after(500,show,event)
```

What is happening is this: when you do `root.after(500, show(event))`, the first thing that happens is that `show(event)` runs *before calling after*. The result of that (`None`) is used in the after, effectively making it `root.after(500, None)`. This causes your whole GUI sleep for half a second. While it is sleeping it is unable to respond to any events which is why you don't see the animation.

Comment: I see, thanks again Bryan. Now I have a different problem, my tooltips stay visible if I enter and exit the button within the 500ms. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @Symon: a comment isn't the right place to answer that. Short version: don't show the tooltip if the cursor has moved out during that 500ms. Or, during your handling of `<leave>` you cancel any pending "after" job.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i went with your 2nd suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.tix import *
root = Tk()

MyButtn = Button(root, text="Hello")
MyButtn.grid()

ToolTp = Balloon()
ToolTp.bind_widget(MyButtn, balloonmsg="My ToolTip example")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)